# adb shell screenrecord result is a black screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I am using a bacth file to capture and transfer to a PC, using a virtual emulator called nox.

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin"
nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62025
.
.
.
nox_adb shell screenrecord --verbose --size 1280x720 --bit-rate 4000000 --time-limit 20 /sdcard/screenrecord.mp4

nox_adb pull /sdcard/screenrecord.mp4  C:\screenrecording\ScreenRecord_%currenttime%.mp4
```

However, the result is a black screen video.

Rooting phone, The developer configuration state.

Please let me know if it's a matter of permission or virtual machine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHPdK.jpg)

Comment: https://www.bignox.com/  >> nox app player

Comment: Does 'Recorder' in the extras menu panel in the lower right: https://www.bignox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/21.png provide a solution?

Comment: Also based on this reddit thread, you may want to either use the stock emulator for development or look at other emulators: https://www.reddit.com/r/noxappplayer/comments/e8m6o0/noxplayer_6503002_release_note/